# CSS not working on menu with submenu in PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, css, menu, submenu

I am trying to make a vertical drop-down menu with sub-menus, for example:

```
1-
 1-
 2-
  1-
3-
```

I've come up with the function below, but the CSS is not being applied even though it is defined on the page using the following:

```html
<link href="estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

```php
function display_menus($menuIdPai = 0) {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE menuIdPai = ".$menuIdPai) or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
        echo "<ul>";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            echo "<li> <a href='percentagem.php'>".$row['id'].$row['menuNome']."</a>";
            display_menus($row['menuId']);
            echo "</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav"> 
    <?php display_menus(); ?>
</ul>
```

```css
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 150px;
}
ul li {
    position: relative;
}
li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 149px;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
}
ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #E2144A;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I've edited your question to simplify and clarify for future viewers. Please let me know if I've deviated from the original intent of your question.

Comment: Hello, the output of the menu is working. The only is not working is the css in that menu.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS is not being applied because your HTML output is incorrect. In the following code:

```
<ul id="nav"> 
    <?php display_menus(); ?>
</ul>
```

the call to `display_menus()` produces its own `<ul>...</ul>` tags, so you end up with:

```
<ul id="nav"><ul> ...
</ul></ul>
```

This is, of course, not valid HTML. One solution to this is to skip the `<ul>...</ul>` tags in the HTML:

```
<?php display_menus(); ?>
```

and adjust `display_menus()` to output the `id="nav"` attribute only to the root menu (when `$menuIdPai == 0`):

```
function display_menus($menuIdPai = 0) {

/* Added $id variable: */

    $id = ($menuIdPai == 0 ? ' id="nav"' : ''); /* Note space before id */

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE menuIdPai = ".$menuIdPai) or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {

/* Added $id here: */

        echo "<ul$id>";

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            echo "<li> <a href='percentagem.php'>".$row['id'].$row['menuNome']."</a>";
            display_menus($row['menuId']);
            echo "</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
}
```

Note that you will also produce incorrect HTML if `$row['id']` or `$row['menuNome']` happens to contain `<` or `&` characters. You should probably escape the latter with [`htmlspecialchars($row['menuNome'])`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php). Probably not the first, depending on what kind of values you have for the `id`'s.

**Note also** that the MySQL extension is deprecated and no longer maintained. You should be using [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) these days.